# Create an image in code and display it into UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create an image. By checking the size, I can see that image has been created. But I am unable to assign that image as image property of UIImageView. Please help.

```
let imageRenderer=UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.view.bounds.size)
book = imageRenderer.image { c in
    let ctx=c.cgContext
    ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
    ctx.setLineWidth(5)
    let x=self.view.bounds.maxX
    let y=self.view.bounds.maxY
    ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x:x/16,y:x/8))
    ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x/2, y: x/4))
    ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x-x/16, y: x/8))
    ctx.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: x-x/16, y: y-x/8))
    ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x/2, y: y-x/16))
    ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x/16, y: y-x/8))
    ctx.closePath()
}
self.image.image = book!
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Try set `self.image.image = imageRenderer.image { ... }` **Note**: `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` is available only 10.0+

Comment: No error, just image is not showing.

Comment: I am trying code for iOS 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add lines but not paint color for them.

You can pain color for them by calling

```
ctx.strokePath()
```

right after (inside the closure)

```
ctx.closePath()
```

More information you can read here

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1454490-strokepath

Comment: Thanks for your help.